# Pymodbus RTU connection troubles

Tags: python, pymodbus3

I am a beginner with both python and modbus and I'm trying to control a fan connected to a serial port with pymodbus for hours now. Using a proprietary software from the manufacturer I was able to control the fan, so the connection itself works.  Yet, my own code does not.

According to the manual the fan is set to the following values:

mode: RTU

baudrate: 19200

parity: even

timeout: 1

slave ID: 247 (F7h)

databits: 8

I modified the pymodbus example code from the [Pymodbus Library Examples](http://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/synchronous-client.html). This is my code:

```
from pymodbus3.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient
Fan = ModbusClient(method='rtu',port ='/dev/ttymxc1', parity = 'E', baudrate='19200', timeout=1)
connection = Fan.connect()
a = Fan.write_register(2,1, unit=0xF7)
b = Fan.read_holding_registers(2,1, unit = 0xF7)
Fan.close()
```

Both the read and write command result in the following error:

```
pymodbus3.exceptions.ModbusIOException: Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Server responded with bad response
```

The same message I get even when the cable is not plugged in.

Does anyone have a suggestion what's wrong?

Comment: try to increase `timeout`. and maybe the problem be on server side.

Comment: Do you set execute permission to `/dev/ttymxc1` ?

Comment: @ Benyamin: Thanks for your comments. Yes, I increased timeout, however it had no effect. I din not change the execute permission from its default. However, since I could not solve the problem with pymodbus, I switched to minimalmodbus, which did the job well.

Comment: You must did changed permission of  `/dev/ttymxc1`

Answer (score -1):

Timeout is the time for the port to wait for an answer.

Set the timeout to something like ~2000, 1 is 1ms and they probably meant 1s.

And try also address 1 (if the above is not working), check also if the Modbus address can be configured to something else (it might be some switchs on the fan).

Comment: Timeout argument unit in `ModbusSerialClient()` is second, not milliseconds.